# Remove line breaks in a FASTA file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I have a fasta file where the sequences are broken up with newlines. I'd like to remove the newlines. Here's an example of my file:

```
>accession1
ATGGCCCATG
GGATCCTAGC
>accession2
GATATCCATG
AAACGGCTTA
```

I'd like to convert it into this:

```
>accession1 ATGGCCCATGGGATCCTAGC
>accession2 GATATCCATGAAACGGCTTA
```

i want a second file which contains two columns. Accession numbers in first, followed by sequences in second.

Comment: Please gives us some more data. Is every accession followed by exactly two DNA sequences? What determines the patterns that surround the accession name (i.e. why is it `(> )` in one case and `{> }` in the next)?

Comment: No worries. Please [edit your question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/189873/edit) to add the extra information.

Comment: Again, please edit your question with this additional information. As you can see, the formatting in the comments is horrible and not everyone reads them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Awk:

```
awk '/^>/&&NR>1{print "";}{printf "%s",/^>/ ? $0" " : $0}' file                                                                                          
>accession1 ATGGCCCATGGGATCCTAGC
>accession2 GATATCCATGAAACGGCTTA
```